# C# System.Threading.ThreadStateException when trying to use Clipboard.SetImage()

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, forms, exception

I have a context menu option that makes screenshots:

```
trayMenu.MenuItems.Add("Make a screenshot", makeScreenShot);

private void makeScreenShot(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Screenshot currentScreenshot = new Screenshot();
    }
```

And in the `Screenshot` class I have this commands:

```
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetImage(screenshot);
```

And everything is OK when I am using this context option, BUT I also use a special .dll that helps me to make some shortcut combinations. One of these combinations has the same event handler.

```
 HotKeysManager manager = new HotKeysManager();
 manager.AddHotKey(new HotKeyCombination(new Keys[] { Keys.LControlKey, Keys.E }, makeScreenShot));

private void makeScreenShot()
    {
        Screenshot screenshot = new Screenshot();
    }
```

The problem is, when I am trying to set an image in the clipboard, using the shortcut combination, it causes `System.Threading.ThreadStateException`.

The exception throws here: `Clipboard.Clear();`

Exception description:

*Exception of type "System.Threading.ThreadStateException" appeared in System.Windows.Forms.dll, but was not handled in user code 
More information: The current thread must be specified as a single-threaded stream container (STA), that calls OLE became possible. Check that your Main function is marked attribute STAThreadAttribute.
If this exception handler is available, program execution can be continued safely.*

Comment: What is the message from the exception?

Comment: Which line throws the actual exception?

Comment: Clipboard.SetImage() trows this exception

Comment: Which thread calls `Clipboard.Clear()` when this exception occurs?

Comment: How can I take this information?

Comment: This is old but I discovered the same issue, basically it happens when you set the clipboard from a sync method. It also seems related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942835/setting-clipboard-content-using-a-background-task-windows-10-uwp)