# Setting Clipboard content using a Background Task [Windows 10] [UWP]

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm working on a Universal Windows 10 App. At the moment I have a background task that gets triggered once the user receives a notification. The purpose of this BG task is to copy the content of the notification. The problem is that the Clipboard.setcontent method appears to be single threaded as opposed to the multi threaded BG task. I have tried using the corewindow dispatcher but that didn't work, I also tried using tasks. Could someone point me out to the solution please?

E.g. the following code in a background task throws the exception:

> Activating a single-threaded class from MTA is not supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000001D).

Code:

```
var dataPackage = new DataPackage { RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy };
dataPackage.SetText("Hello World!");
Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
```

Answer (score 4):

Save the content somewhere and assign the string to the Clipboard while the app is about to resume.

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
    var dataPackage = new DataPackage { RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy };
    dataPackage.SetText("Hello World!");
    Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);

    getText();
});

private async void getText()
{
    string t = await Clipboard.GetContent().GetTextAsync();
}
```

Comment: the content has to be copied instantly, there must be a way around this.

Comment: I tried that, the BG task does not return an exception, but it also doesn't copy anything.

Comment: @SaeedSefrini Tested it, works fine actually, I add the getText() method to get the Text from Clipboard.

Comment: Just to be sure, is this the dispatcher that you're using CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher ?

The debugger doesn't go past calling the dispatcher.

Comment: from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.aspx

Comment: I have tried  CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;

await dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
            var dataPackage = new DataPackage { RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy };
            dataPackage.SetText(details.UserInput.ToString());
            Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
            getText();
            });
But the debugger doesn't go past initializing the dispatcher. Thanks a lot for trying to help btw, highly appreciated. :)

Comment: I did not tried something like CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher, but instead I directly use Dispatcher in my xaml.cs code, if you cannot find, use ctrl+.(dot) to add the namespace directly.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I'm creating a background task, it's not a page.

Comment: yes, but what I consider is you should have the place that can attach the onProgress or onCompleted events for background task, what I do is to put the Clipboard manipulation on there. Search for "Background task" sample for windows store app and do the samething on uwp app.

Comment: The problem with what you're suggesting is that the app must be running for the content to be copied. I guess I should just lose hope :(